# Xcode shows popup but there is no errors

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-simulator

[image: popup image]
Working with my application It goes well but has met into a problem with Xcode. When I try to run the application on the iPhone simulator this message always pops up:

> "A coordinated app install already exists for com.apk.ios with intent IXCoordinatorIntentUpdating (creator InstallCoordination Simple SPI) but request by CoreSimulatorBridge (pid 677) was for intent IXCoordinatorIntentInitiating"

What is wrong? There are no errors when trying to build the app. Has tried to clean the build.

Comment: Reset simulator from Hardware->Erase all content and settings...

Answer (score 0):

Erasing all content and settings is not always necessary as @**user3344236** stated.

Please make sure to delete the app that you are trying to install from the iOS Simulator. That'll probably solve your problem.

**Why this occurs?**

In my case something went wrong while Xcode is trying to install the app on the simulator. Everything is frozen and I had to restart the Mac manually.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that works for me:

Reason:

Either the App store or something else tool is downloading the same app with the same identifier at the time Xcode is trying to launch the same app on the Simulator or on MAC.

Solution:

Need to stop/delete all the running installs of the app with the same identifier. (How to stop -> that can be figured out to see either App Store or any other tool ) Then try again to launch the app with Xcode, this time it succeeds.

No need to Reboot the simulator/ Mac or reinstall Xcode.

Thanks, Hope this will help someone.